# Javascript set scrollbar to bottom of container

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I would like to set scrollbar on container to bottom automatically when page loads.

I tried this:

```
  var messages = document.getElementById('messages'); 
  messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:jquery], but you do not appear to be actually using jQuery. Are you? Are jQuery solutions acceptable to you? If not, you should [edit] to remove that tag.

Comment: Some people have tweaked your code to make it more easily readable. This means that the code in the question may not be exactly the same as the code you actually have, though it *should* be equivalent, if they were careful. Please review the code in the question and ensure that you are happy with it as an accurate description of the code you have. If not, you can [edit] to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try the following code, and worked perfectly. try this, set scroll auto bottom.

```
$("#messagebox").scrollTop($("#messagebox")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This is more easier if you are  using jQuery.

```
$("#yourDiv").scrollTop($("#yourDiv").prop('scrollHeight'))
```

Comment: Add at least a bit of explanation, just tossing a line of code OP's way won't help.

Comment: yes please add some information about your code to help others who land on this page in the future, and explain how/why it solves the problem.

Comment: thanks, but where i put code, need i make new js... can you help me? More information please, i am noob and sorry my engli

Comment: You can use this code in any **js** file that you can access your **div** element. Even you can use this code inside the html page within `<script>` tag. But the best way to use in a  **JS** file.  Put this code inside `$( document ).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the css, add "max-height" for vertical scroll bar, see below:

```
#container{ 
   height: 453px; 
   width: 800px; 
   border: 1px solid black;
   max-height: 100px;
}
```

For the horizontal scroll bar I have add the 'wrap' attribute with value 'off' :

```
<textarea id="message" wrap='off' rows="9" cols="97" style="background-color: yellow;"></textarea>
```